# Remove keys with apt_key gives "Invalid key_id" in Ansible task

Tags: ansible, key, apt

I'm trying to use Ansible to purge all of the older apt keys that are in my */etc/apt/trustedb.key* file. I have the task as part of a role to be run on my Ubuntu-like boxes because the old keys are colliding with the keys that are in the */etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d* directory.

*role/vars/main.yml*

```yaml
apt_depricated_key_ids:
  - 0x34D6F263286829BCAC22B44EA62A5ECC316B177D
  - 0x418A7F2FB0E1E6E7EABF6FE8C2E73424D59097AB
  - 0x2EBF997C15BDA244B6EBF5D84773BD5E130D1D45
  - 0x1958A549614CE21CFC27F4BAA8A515F046D7E7CF
  - 0x1958A549614CE21CFC27F4BAA8A515F046D7E7CF
  - 0x74E4CE730C706BE5C646499A133EAF26736E4F0B
```

*role/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- name: "Remove keyrings from depricated APT trusted.gpg"
  apt_key:
    file: "/etc/apt/trustdb.gpg"
    id: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  when: (ansible_lsb.codename is defined) and ("ansible_lsb.codename in lookup('vars','ubuntu_22_04_codenames')")
  loop: "{{ [apt_depricated_key_ids] }}"
```

I keep on getting the following errors `"msg": "Invalid key_id"`

I've tried multiple ways of formatting the value based off the documentation. None seem to work

- `0x34D6F263286829BCAC22B44EA62A5ECC316B177D`
- `"0x34D6F263286829BCAC22B44EA62A5ECC316B177D"`
- `34D6F263286829BCAC22B44EA62A5ECC316B177D`
- `"34D6F263286829BCAC22B44EA62A5ECC316B177D"`

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if, instead of using in them in a loop you test with the first key only and do `id: 0x34D6F263286829BCAC22B44EA62A5ECC316B177D` in the `apt_key` task right away? Does it work then?

Comment: Also `loop: "{{ [apt_depricated_key_ids] }}"` > why are you giving a list of list, here? This might well be the issue, you want `loop: "{{ apt_depricated_key_ids }}"`, obviously. Or `loop: "{{ apt_depricated_key_ids | default([]) }}"` if your goal was to offer a fail safe in case of undefined list of keys.